Quantized ADC Error
I am using an ADC and found a strange sawtooth deviation between the real value and the measured value when sweeping across a voltage range. From my research, it looks like this generally happens when you are measuring a signal which is smaller than the adc's resolution. But, in my case, the adc has many points in between the sawtooth edges which seems to suggest that it has better resolution. Is there any way to fix this issue?


This is from INL and DNL (and the overall error could be from the source of is not calibrated or has better write than the ADC), it is inherent to the ADC. To get rid of this difference you would need a multi channel approach and or heavy calibration. Or switch to a better ADC.

Sounds good. I forgot to add, but the ADC used not have this issue before someone possibly shorted the board on a metal table. Do you think it could have been caused by damage?

What is your ADC?

https://www.ti.com/product/ADS8353
ADS8353
